# How to create nested vuetify navigation drawer?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a case here where i have one navigation drawer which i want to keep fixed with icons in it and i want another navigation drawer which can be opened and closed adjacent to the fixed drawer without overlapping it. I have got the nav drawer to work but it actually overlaps the whole drawer. 
This is a link to the [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/vYEOYrr?editors=1010).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      actions: [{
          icon: 'android'
        },
        {
          icon: 'dashboard'
        },
        {
          icon: 'question_answer'
        },
      ],
      drawer: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer fixed width="70">
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile v-for="action in actions" :key="action">
          <v-icon>{{action.icon}}</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-navigation-drawer temporary app v-model="drawer">
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar fixed app class="ml-5 pl-3">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Topics</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Again, the navigation drawer should open right next to the fixed drawer and not overlap it.P.S. i am using vuetify 1.5

Comment: Do you expect it to "push" the fixed drawer, or simply be to the right of it?

Comment: it should be to the right of it, the fixed drawer should stay where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it just with props. You could add some custom CSS for when the 2nd drawer is open...

```
.v-navigation-drawer--open.d2 {
    left: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/PPEENlESKV)

Comment: yeah i was hoping if i can do it with just props somehow? what if i also want to push the title and the icon to the right when the second nav drawer opens, then another class to push the title to the right?

Comment: Not with 1.5.. maybe in 2.x. Yeah, that's why I asked if you wanted it to "push" the fixed drawer before